# Execute python from bash and see its log on terminal

Tags: python, linux, bash, logging

I have the following:

> 1. main.py python script which while running writes to main.log.
> 2. I am writing a sh file.

I want to execute the python script from sh file and to see in the terminal window all the log which is written to the main.log file while executing.

Currently I am doing it by open a terminal and execute the script and open another terminal and writing

```
tail -f main.log.
```

Thanks.

Comment: Simply use `&` after the command you use for launching your python script to launch it as a background process. Then, you can `tail -f` in the same terminal.

Comment: could you change your script to log to stdout instead? You can redirect the output to terminal and a file later if necessary: `python main.py | tee main.log`.

Comment: @J.F.Sebastian: You're right, that's done.

Answer (score 1):

Simply use `&` after the command you use for launching your python script to launch it as a background process. Then, you can `tail -f` in the same terminal.

Comment: I still have a problem where I make the "sudo python3 ... & sudo tail -f Main.log", it does the work and shows me the log to the terminal. The thing is that after this command, I have to run another command in the continue of the script, but the tail -f runs without ending and the next command in the script doesn't get executed. How can I solve it ? Thanks.

Comment: You probably should read some bash scripting tutorial past this point.

Answer (score 0):

I've used the `nohup` command in the past to essentially disconnect from a process and let it run in the background. The syntax would be something along the lines of `nohup <program execution and options> > main.log &`

Then you can `tail -f main.log` to watch it update in real time.

I've had issues with `nohup` where a .sh either runs infinitely or has a syntax error, so definitely check for correctness before running. You probably won't catch this unless you change the end of the statement to `2>&1 &` to get `stderr` to redirect to `stdout`, but since you're running a python script, I don't think this would help you.

Lastly, you can kill the process created by `nohup` by either killing the `PID` given to you by the command, or using `ps -ef | grep <main.log>`